# ASP.NET CORE MVC New reservation on car Error:ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Im doing project in ASP.NET CORE MVC Rent a car. i have done to user who log in in aplication and have a table of cars. when he press bottun for reservation, a need to fill other information, and i want to in select type for client is already fill name of him and car which is choose. I did that but i have error ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items'). So does anyone know how I can resolve this.

Comment: And can you tell  pls where this parameter items is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you didn' try this

```
ViewBag.MjestoPre = _dbContext.Mjesto.Select( i=> new SelectListItem 
                                  { 
                                    Value=i.Idmjesto,
                                    Text=i.Naziv
                                   }).ToList();
```

Assuming MjestoPreuzimanja is int or string

```
<select asp-for="MjestoPreuzimanja" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.MjestoPre"> 
<option>Odaberite...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much...but now data dont want to store in database... so do you maybe know how can i solve that

Comment: @AlexNorth Yes, I  think I know what is wrong. But  a lot of code needs to be changed, so it is better if you create another post where put this changes. I will  post my answer.